# How do I check if var exists in database column and do nothing if it doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, exists

Hi I'm new to mysql and I'm hoping what I'm trying to do is quite easy. The sql below works when there is an entry in planets table under the caption column corresponding to $imgFile. The problem I have is that not all my $imgFiles are in the database. So when this is the case line 3 `$caption=mysql_result($data, '0')` throws this error:

Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/drawapl1/public_html/planet.php on line 3

How do I change this so that it only sets $caption where $imgFile exists?

```
$retrieveCaption="SELECT caption from planets where image='$imgFile'";

$data=mysql_query($retrieveCaption); 

$caption=mysql_result($data, '0');

echo $caption;
```

Comment: You've made 9 questions so far. It's about time you learn to format code.

Comment: I'm sorry you don't like the formatting. If you could point out where I'm going wrong maybe I can improve. I'm fairly new to coding but have recently started doing more as a hobby.

Comment: He's talking about formatting code as code samples in questions/answers on this site. You can do this by selecting your code sample and then hit the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could catch empty result sets with `mysql_num_rows()`.

```
if( mysql_num_rows($data) == 0 ) {
    // No results returned
```

Or use a function which doesn't throw a warning in such cases, like `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
if( $row ) {
    $caption = $row['caption'];
} else {
    $caption = "Default";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can ask MySQL if it found anything:

`if ( 0 < mysql_num_rows($data) ) { // results`

If no results, don't use mysql_result.

Also: the '0' wants to be a 0 (an int instead of a string).

Also: you should escape all input into SQL queries, so you should escape $imgFile